# Find the power series of $f(x)=\frac{16}{x^2+4}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Then, integrate it from $0$ to $2$, and call it $S$. $S$ should be an infinite series.
What are the first few terms of $S$ ($5$ terms)?

I'm not sure I fully understand how to do this so any help would be great.

Comment: Use the *geometric series*

Comment: Though I do think it would be wiser to use a geometric series, if you have the series for arctangent readily available, you could plug in the correct argument and then differentiate term by term.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make it look like: $f(x) = K\dfrac{1}{1+\triangle}$. The $K = \dfrac{16}{x^2}, \triangle = \dfrac{4}{x^2}\implies f(x) = K\left(1-\triangle+ \triangle^2-\triangle^3 +\cdots\right)$. Can you finish it off?